# 404 Flask Deploy in 2008R2 - iis7

Tags: python, flask, iis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using wfastcgi3.0 with python3.4.

Even though I strictly followed this guide in https://netdot.co/2015/03/09/flask-on-iis/

I still got 404.....

My webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="FlaskFastCGI" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python34\python.exe|C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\app\FLASKTEST" />
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="myapp.app" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

myapp.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from FastCGI via IIS!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use python version after 3.6 with iis.follow this post steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171787/11147346.

assign the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site and python folder. and at the tim eof installation install the python for all users.